# FacebookConnect redirect no longer works

Tags: javascript, facebook, asp.net-mvc-3

I have been successfully doing a redirect after FacebookConnect for a while, but it has now stopped working.  The only thing I can think I may have changed is updating my Facebook references using NuGet.  Here is my code, can anybody tell me why it no longer works?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function () {

                window.FB.init({ appId: 'xxxx', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true });

                $('#fbLogin').click(function () {
                    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function (response) {
                        alert('The status of the session is: ' + response.status);
                        if (response.status == 'connected') {
                            window.location.href = '@Account.Urls.FacebookConnect()';
                        }
                    }, { perms: 'email' });
                });
            });



        </script>

       <fb:login-button autologoutlink="false" perms="email" id="fbLogin">

       </fb:login-button>
```

Whether I put an alert for response.status == 'connected' or not, neither alert is reached

Comment: Why are you subscribing to the event only on click on the button? Try subscribing to the event directly after FB.init.

Comment: In Firebug auth.statusChange is not triggered when connecting at all, even when I remove the onClick event

Comment: Got it working by using auth.authResponseChange instead of auth.statusChange

Answer (score 0):

Got it working with a mixture of CBroe's suggestion and using auth.authResponseChange instead of auth.statusChange